# What is the best way to fetch api in redux?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, redux

How to write best way to fetch api resource in react app while we use redux in application.

my actions file is actions.js

```
export const getData = (endpoint) => (dispatch, getState) => {
   return fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/getdata').then(
      response => response.json()).then(
        json =>
        dispatch({
       type: actionType.SAVE_ORDER,
       endpoint,
       response:json
    }))
}
```

is it best way to fetch api?

Comment: This looks good

Comment: using middleware is a lot cleaner IMO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The above code is fine.But there are few points you should look to.

1. If you want to show a Loader to user for API call then you might need some changes.
2. You can use async/await the syntax is much cleaner.
3. Also on API success/failure you might want to show some notification to user. Alternatively, You can check in componentWillReceiveProps to show notification but the drawback will be it will check on every props changes.So I mostly avoid it.

To cover this problems you can do:

```
import { createAction } from 'redux-actions';

const getDataRequest = createAction('GET_DATA_REQUEST');
const getDataFailed = createAction('GET_DATA_FAILURE');
const getDataSuccess = createAction('GET_DATA_SUCCESS');

export function getData(endpoint) {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(getDataRequest());
        const { error, response } = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/getdata');
        if (response) {
        dispatch(getDataSuccess(response.data));
        //This is required only if you want to do something at component level
        return true; 
        } else if (error) {
        dispatch(getDataFailure(error));
        //This is required only if you want to do something at component level
        return false;
        }
    };
}
```

In your component:

```
this.props.getData(endpoint)
.then((apiStatus) => {
    if (!apiStatus) {
    // Show some notification or toast here
    }
});
```

Your reducer will be like:

```
case 'GET_DATA_REQUEST': {
    return {...state, status: 'fetching'}
}

case 'GET_DATA_SUCCESS': {
    return {...state, status: 'success'}
}

case 'GET_DATA_FAILURE': {
    return {...state, status: 'failure'}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using middleware is the most sustainable way to do API calls in React + Redux applications. If you are using Observables, aka, Rxjs then look no further than [redux-observable](https://redux-observable.js.org/).

Otherwise, you can use [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) or [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga).

If you are doing a quick prototype, then making a simple API call from the component using fetch is good enough. For each API call you will need three actions like:

1. **LOAD_USER** - action used set loading state before API call.
2. **LOAD_USER_SUCC** - when API call succeeds. Dispatch on from `then` block.
3. **LOAD_USER_FAIL** - when API call fails and you might want to set the value in redux store. Dispatch from `catch` block.

Example:

```
function mounted() {
    store.dispatch(loadUsers());

    getUsers()
        .then((users) => store.dispatch(loadUsersSucc(users)))
        .catch((err) => store.dispatch(loadUsersFail(err));
}
```